# How to get the complete position (top and left ) of a cell in a table row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a Table in React JS.

I have this code demo - This is my Demo in CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/2wp7jk23kr

I have multiple columns in my table. Now in any column say column 1 to 10, I want to have a function which can calculate the position of the particular cell element (div). How can I get position of a particular div in a cell of a table. Please answer with respect to my demo. I am trying to get the position of data cells not header cells

I am using React and also vanilla JS to some small extent. I cannot use jQuery.

If possible, you can kindly fork/modify to show how to introduce this feature to my table.

I am not able to find solutions that is working on my code.

Please tell me how to find position with respect to both table and page

Comment: No it is not same. You should kindly see the demo table before suggesting it as duplicate

Comment: I see what you mean; however you should have described your problem (dynamically generated `div`s) **in the post** instead of making the reader infer it from the demo.

Comment: When you say position – do you mean x, y coordinates? If so should it be relative to the page or table?.

Comment: Please tell me wrt to both page as well as table

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the cell offset within the table you could use `getBoundingClientRect()`

```js
const tableRect = document.querySelector('table').getBoundingClientRect();
const cellRect  = document.querySelector('#cell').getBoundingClientRect();
    
    console.log(
        cellRect.left - tableRect.left,  // x
        cellRect.top  - tableRect.top    // y
    )
```

```css
#cell { background: gold; }
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td id="cell">Find Me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: getBoundingClientRect  on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: can you kindly fork and show it in my example. It will be of great help. Kindly share the forked url

Comment: I havn't worked with React before (more of a Vue-kinda-guy) – but I'll give it a look :-)

Comment: Question – what will you be using the coordinates for?